# Decode with known PSK in DTLS

Tags: wireshark

I have a wireshark capture of implementations of DTLS protocol. I have the PSK and I have converted it to corresponding hex.DTLS uses `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8` cipher suite.

How can I decrypt the data in wieshark(1.12.7)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the capture on Wireshark, and:

- Rigth-click on a DTLS packet
- Then select "Protocol Preferences" --> "Datagram Transport Layer Preferences"
- There you can put your PSK in HEX format.

Finally, when you select a DTLS packet, on the details section you have a second tab with the decrypted DTLS data.

[image]